# Parsing output in linux with grep, awk, tr, sed

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

Hi I want to pares command output in linux below is the out put

```
addr {
  bus: "scsi"
  index: 0
}
vmdisk_uuid: "00aa6d13-e9e1-4df8-8af3-0a326489130f"
container_id: 774
vmdisk_size: 268435456000
addr {
  bus: "scsi"
  index: 1
}
vmdisk_uuid: "5b006fe4-a15c-490a-b589-5cdbc1dca155"
source_nfs_path: "/SureContainer/OCB/manual_81E33418-AC72-4D02-B9D2-0CF31D3B0EED/0E704F98-0EBF-4FB4-B538-142B7D0AA8F4_99999.raw"
container_id: 774
vmdisk_size: 536870912
addr {
  bus: "scsi"
  index: 2
}
vmdisk_uuid: "3b6b4229-ae76-42b0-815f-e2f6ee4d51e4"
source_nfs_path: "/SureContainer/OCB/manual_81E33418-AC72-4D02-B9D2-0CF31D3B0EED/0E704F98-0EBF-4FB4-B538-142B7D0AA8F4_99999.raw"
container_id: 774
vmdisk_size: 536870912
addr {
  bus: "scsi"
  index: 3
}
vmdisk_uuid: "187f0a54-00ae-49c9-929e-c85d7fcdcc51"
source_nfs_path: "/SureContainer/OCB/manual_81E33418-AC72-4D02-B9D2-0CF31D3B0EED/0E704F98-0EBF-4FB4-B538-142B7D0AA8F4_99999.raw"
container_id: 774
vmdisk_size: 536870912
addr {
  bus: "scsi"
  index: 4
}
vmdisk_uuid: "9dbad5d7-fc19-44fe-8652-8579a337c337"
source_nfs_path: "/SureContainer/OCB/manual_81E33418-AC72-4D02-B9D2-0CF31D3B0EED/0E704F98-0EBF-4FB4-B538-142B7D0AA8F4_99999.raw"
container_id: 774
vmdisk_size: 536870912
```

I tried out below with command

```
acli vm.disk_get SureMC | grep -e index -e source_nfs_path |grep -v "index: 0" | awk '{print $2}'
```

i am able to parse above output to below

```
1
"/SureContainer/OCB/manual_81E33418-AC72-4D02-B9D2-0CF31D3B0EED/0E704F98-0EBF-4FB4-B538-142B7D0AA8F4_99999.raw"
2
"/SureContainer/OCB/manual_81E33418-AC72-4D02-B9D2-0CF31D3B0EED/0E704F98-0EBF-4FB4-B538-142B7D0AA8F4_99999.raw"
3
"/SureContainer/OCB/manual_81E33418-AC72-4D02-B9D2-0CF31D3B0EED/0E704F98-0EBF-4FB4-B538-142B7D0AA8F4_99999.raw"
4
"/SureContainer/OCB/manual_81E33418-AC72-4D02-B9D2-0CF31D3B0EED/0E704F98-0EBF-4FB4-B538-142B7D0AA8F4_99999.raw"
```

But i am expecting below output and i am not able to do that please help

```
1="/SureContainer/OCB/manual_81E33418-AC72-4D02-B9D2-0CF31D3B0EED/0E704F98-0EBF-4FB4-B538-142B7D0AA8F4_99999.raw"

2="/SureContainer/OCB/manual_81E33418-AC72-4D02-B9D2-0CF31D3B0EED/0E704F98-0EBF-4FB4-B538-142B7D0AA8F4_99999.raw"

3="/SureContainer/OCB/manual_81E33418-AC72-4D02-B9D2-0CF31D3B0EED/0E704F98-0EBF-4FB4-B538-142B7D0AA8F4_99999.raw"

4="/SureContainer/OCB/manual_81E33418-AC72-4D02-B9D2-0CF31D3B0EED/0E704F98-0EBF-4FB4-B538-142B7D0AA8F4_99999.raw"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this,

```
acli vm.disk_get SureMC | grep -e index -e source_nfs_path a | grep -v "index: 0" |sed 'N;s/\n/ /' | awk '{ print $2,$4}' OFS="="
```

(Or)

```
acli vm.disk_get SureMC | grep -e index -e source_nfs_path a | grep -v "index: 0" | awk '{print $2}' | sed 'N;s/\n/=/'
```